# click event associated to two modal divs

Tags: events, html, click, overlay

I have an issue related to click events on different modal divs.

I have a modal div 'A' which shows an overlay div with some info. This div is show by clicking i.e. a button A. So, when it's shown if i click outside the overlapped div, i want this to close.

I have another div 'B' which shows an overlay div with some other info. This div is show by clicking i.e. a button B. So, when it's shown if i click outside the overlapped div, i want this to close.

In both cases i use $(window).click() for managing them.

The question is that i need that when once i click on button 'A', it's corresponding div come up and if i click on button 'B' I want div 'A' close and div 'B' come up and viceversa.

how can i handle multiple clicks events for multiple modal divs?

Thanks.y

Comment: Have you tried using the `onClick()` methods of buttons A and B to handle that? Or is there a method of identifying which button triggered the event?

Comment: Yes, i used onClick() methods for such task but need a method or strategy to handle multiple overlay div's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you want, but...

Assuming your buttons and divs are of class "overlay", and have IDs as in Rolando's example ("buttonA", "divA"; "buttonB", "divB"; etc.):

```
$(".overlay").filter(":button").click(function() {
    var callid = /button(.+)/.exec($(this).attr("id"))[1];

    $("div.overlay[id$=" + callid + "]").show();
    $("div.overlay:not([id$=" + callid + "])").hide();
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KXeXj/

The only issue is the "clicking outside the div to close it" part; I tried using `$(":not(.overlay)").click(function() {$("div.overlay").hide()})`, but that didn't seem to work as it just kept the `div`s hidden whatever you clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very good point of view!!! i need to adapt it but it's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a staring:

```
$('#buttonA").click(function(){
      $(#divA").show();
      $(#divB").hide();
})
```

Comment: I was thinking it should be something simple like this (and it'd be symmetric for button B), but I wonder if domoindal meant he wanted a way to iterate through all overlay divs without having to list them explicitly, and trigger based on the button without having to list all the buttons. Hm... Also, check your quote marks.